# Using a sprite sheet with multiple sprites

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, sprite

Hey guys so I have a sprite sheet with multiple sprites that I want to use to animate a website
using canvas.

However the problem I am having is I don't know how to go about reading in only the frames that I need.

Example:

```
1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2
3 3 4 4
4 4 4 4
```

Here I have 4 different sprites that I want to animate.
How would I go about retrieving and animating the correct frames?

P.S I'm using javascript.

Comment: Using an element that has the size of one frame in your image, you just change the background position to get to the other frames.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial on getting what you need accomplished. https://www.udacity.com/course/cs255

Comment: @adeneo how would I create the animation for that then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Retrieving and Playing multiple sprites on a spritesheet**

**Retrieving:** Create an object defining each sprite's x,y,width,height and save the objects in an array

```
sprite1.push({x:0,y:0,width:20,height:30});
sprite1.push({x:20,y:0,width:20,height:30});
sprite1.push({x:40,y:0,width:20,height:30});

// do the same for sprites #2-4
```

Depending on your actual spritesheet, this code can be optimized--especially if the sprites are equally sized and spaced.

**Playing a frame:** Use the clipping verision of context.drawImage to "play" a sprite frame:

```
function playSpriteFrame(sprite,frameIndex,canvasX,canvasY){

    // get the current sprite from the sprite array

    var s=sprite[frameIndex];

    // draw that sprite on the canvas at canvasX/canvasY

    context.drawImage(
        spritesheet,                      // the spritesheet image
        s.x,s,y,s.width,s.height,         // clip from spritesheet
        canvasX,canvasY,s.width,s.height  // draw to canvas
    );

}
```

**Example usage:** Draw frame #2 of sprite1 at canvas 100,100

```
// Remember arrays start at element 0 so frame#2 is at array element 1

playSpriteFrame(sprite1,1,100,100);
```

You didn't ask about how to create an animation loop, but here is starter info anyway:

- the old way would be looping with setInterval or setTimer
- the new (better) way is with requestAnimationFrame