# Change sprites in open source pacman

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pacman

I am trying to change the sprites in an online `HTML5` Canvas Pacman game.

At the moment, I have tried to change the original image:
http://kasperbjerreskov.dk/games/pacman/sprites/spritesheet1.png (original)
spritesheet.png  (edited)

But that doesn't seem to work.

I have found something in the code, that looks like its drawing the sprites, but i am not sure how to do this.

It's an open source edition, that can be found: http://pacman.shaunew.com/redmine/projects/pacman/repository
Still using the original source, except the new image.

Comment: What do you mean by "change sprites"? If you just want to draw one sprite from the spritesheet you can use the clipping version of [`context.drawImage`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446087/using-a-sprite-sheet-with-multiple-sprites/21461197#21461197).

Comment: I Want to change the Pacman Sprite to a vacuum cleaner, and the ghosts to "dust bunnies"

Comment: I don't know Pacman, but I assume vacuum-cleaner and dust-bunnies are existing sprites on the spritesheet. Draw your vacuum-cleaner sprite and your dust-bunnies sprite from the spritesheet using the clipping version of `context.drawImage`. For an example, see this previous [Stackoverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446087/using-a-sprite-sheet-with-multiple-sprites/21461197#21461197).

Comment: Pacman is that little yellow circle with a mouth, but I have no idea on how to do this change or where to make it, as I am not that great with JavaScript.
Is it somehow possible to make it in the same way that it is now?

Comment: I've posted an answer showing you how to clip individual sprites from a spritesheet. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out any sprite from the spritesheet using the clipping form of `context.drawImage`:

```
context.drawImage(
    // from the spritesheet
    spritesheet,
    // go to x,y on the spritesheet and cut out a width x height sized subimage
    spriteX, spriteY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight,   
    // and draw that subimage on the canvas at canvasX, canvasY
    canvasX, canvasY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight
);
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// define a few sprite's position on the spritesheet
var pacOpenRight={  x:20,y:20,width:20,height:20 };
var ghostRed={  x:40,y:80,width:20,height:20 };

var spritesheet=new Image();
spritesheet.onload=start;
spritesheet.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/PacmanSpritesheet.png";
function start(){
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    drawSprite(pacOpenRight,50,50);
    drawSprite(ghostRed,70,50);
}

function drawSprite(spriteDef,canvasX,canvasY){
    ctx.drawImage(
        // from the spritesheet
        spritesheet,
        // go to x,y on the spritesheet and 
        //     cut out a width x height sized subimage
        spriteDef.x, spriteDef.y, spriteDef.width, spriteDef.height,   
        // and draw it on the canvas at x,y
        canvasX, canvasY, spriteDef.width, spriteDef.height
    );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```